# Tail and watch, filter and extract string

Tags: shell-script, awk, cut, tail

Lets says I have a file called `test.log` more rows being added all the time:

```
one|two|apple|four|foo1
one|two|pear|four|foo2
one|two|apple|four|foo3
one|two|peach|four|foo4
```

I want to tail it but am only interested in lines that say apple, and I only want to see the string after the last pipe.

To filter by apple I can use:

`tail -f test.log | grep apple`

This outputs:

```
one|two|apple|four|foo1
one|two|apple|four|foo3
```

Now to get the string after the last pipe I thought I could use:

`tail -f test.log | grep apple | awk -F '|' '{print $(NF)}'`

But this outputs nothing.

If I remove the `-f` option from tail it works but then I can't watch my log file.

The problem is awk hangs [as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20515846/967168). I could not make the solution outlined there work for me.

So maybe using cut would be easier than awk. There are a set number of pipes so I could just do:

`cat test.log | grep apple | cut -d\| -f 5`

Outputs:

```
foo1
foo3
```

But when I watch with:

`tail -f test.log | grep apple | cut -d\| -f5`

Again I get no output.

**Is there an one liner I can use to tail this file, filter it, and extract the last bit?**

Comment: Just don't use two pipes. Grep isn't needed, awk can do all the work: `tail -f test.log | awk -F '|' '/apple/{print $NF}'`.

Comment: It was that simple! Thanks @terdon